# Which Krsna went to help the Pandavas?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, bhagavata-purana, pandavas

We know that Lord Krsna was always focussed on helping the Pandavas throughout their lives. Therefore, in the Mahabharata, we see him making frequent trips to  Indraprastha, Hastinapura, Kamyaka and Dvaita Vanas and Upaplavya to help the Pandavas. We also get the idea that Krsna is away on all these visits, as one can see what Krsna says about Shishupala's attack of Dvaraka [when he is away](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11473/where-is-the-account-of-shishupalas-atrocities-in-dvaraka), as also of his sudden arrival back to Dvaraka upon Shalva's attack of Dvaraka.

But in the [69th Chapter of the Dasama Skandha](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/10/69) of Srimad Bhagavatam, we see that Krsna is present in all 16108 palaces of his wives, as well as handling affairs of his kingdom *by being present in more than 16108 places at once*.

If that is the case, then it is logical to assume that only one among the thousands of Krsnas went to Hastinapura and Pragjyotisha and so on. But this contradicts **Krsna's own statements** made in the Rajasuya Yajna, that Shishupala misused the situations where Krsna *was away* from Dvaraka.

So, did **all the Krsnas** leave Dvaraka on these frequent travels, or did only one Krsna make these trips?

Comment: That was a leela performed by Shree Krishna to teach a lesson to Narada muni. Once Narada muni succumbed by ego and pride. He lost his way towards Lord Vishnu. Krishna decides to teach him a lesson that He is the only supreme. He can take an infinite forms at a time when at his will. Lord did not want to take many forms when Shishupala attacked Dwaraka. Krishna allowed Shishupala to attack so that he will complete 100 mistakes and kill him. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shishupala) is the story of boon Krishna gave to Shishupala's mother.

Comment: Krishna is one. By His mere fragment He pervades entire universe; what to speak of 16108 palaces in Dwarka. Sometimes by His illusory energy He expands Himself in many forms. these forms are non-different from each other. Krishna could kill all the demons in no time; but He doesnt do so; if He had done so; which of His glories would we sing and hear. So He performs all this leela for welfare of all the living entities :-)

Comment: I agree with @SreeCharan, I don't think Krishna always multiplied himself, he just did it under certain circumstances.  So yes, when he went to help the Pandavas I don't think he also remained back in Dwaraka.